# How do I evaluate the limit $\lim_{n \to +\infty}(1-(1-p/n)^{[nx]})=1-e^{-px}$?

Tags: calculus, probability, limits, probability-distributions, probability-limit-theorems

**Let $(X_n)_{n\ge 1}$ be a sequence of random variables , $\forall n\ge 1, X_n \sim Geo(p/n)$ with $p>0$ fixed. Study the convergence of $Y_n=X_n/n$ in distribution. (without using charateristic functions)**

**Solution**

Convergence in distribution is equivalence to convergence of the cumulative functions so

$F_{Y_n}(x)=\mathbb{P}(Y_n\le x)=\mathbb{P}(X_n\le xn)=F_{X_n}(nx)$

Considering the cumulative function for the geometric distribution with parameter $p/n$ is $F_{X_n}(x)=1-(1-p/n)^{[x]}, $where $[x]$ is the integer part (floor function), I have that
$\lim_{n \to +\infty} F_{X_n}(nx)=\lim_{n \to +\infty}(1-(1-p/n)^{[nx]})  $

If it weren't for that [.] , i could just say that
$\lim_{n \to +\infty}(1-(1-p/n)^{nx})=1-e^{-px}$ and conclude the limit is an exponential distribution.

**a)How do I deal with that [.]? I feel I can't just suppose  x is an integer since the cumulative function is not only defined for integer numbers.**

Comment: I suggest you use `Y_n` for subscript, to avoid confusion with multiplication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\lfloor u\rfloor=u+O(1)$ for all $u>0$, so we have
\begin{aligned}
\log\left(1-\frac pn\right)^{\lfloor xn\rfloor}
&=\{xn+O(1)\}\left\{-\frac pn+O\left(1\over n^2\right)\right\} \\
&=-px+O\left(\frac1n\right)
\end{aligned}

Consequently, we have
$$
\left(1-\frac pn\right)^{\lfloor nx\rfloor}=e^{-px}+O\left(\frac1n\right)
$$
given that $p$ and $x$ are fixed.

Comment: I am more comfortable with the small o simbol, how can I write O(1) and O(1/n)with small o?

Comment: $O(1)$ is just some bounded quantity (which cannot be replaced with little o), and $O(1/n)$ goes to zero so you can replace this one with $o(1)$.

Comment: In the first multiplication I get $-px+-p/n O(1)+xnO(1/n^2)+O(1)O(1/n^2)=-px+O(1/n)+O(1/n)+O(1/n^2)=-px+O(1/n)+O(1/n^2)$  why 
 is $O(1/n)+O(1/n^2)=O(1/n)$?

Comment: Note that $1/n^2\le 1/n$ for all $n\ge1$.

Comment: and then, what O property should I use?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, that inequality is sufficient for $O(1/n)+O(1/n^2)=O(1/n)$ to hold

Comment: why is $\exp(-px+O(1/n))=\exp(-px)+O(1/n)$? which means $\exp(O(1/n))=1+O(1/n)$, I guess

Comment: Let $a_n=o(1)$ then we have $|e^{a_n}-1|\le\sum_{k\ge1}|a_n|^k/k!\le |a_n|\sum_{m\ge0}|a_n|^m={|a_n|\over1-|a_n|}$. For large $n$ we have $|a_n|\le1/2$ so $|e^{a_n}-1|\le2|a_n|$, which means $e^{a_n}=1+O(|a_n|)$.

Comment: You use the little o wrongly. From the continuity argument you should say $\lim_{n\to\infty}\exp(-px+O(1/n))=\exp(-px+\lim_{n\to\infty}O(1/n))=\exp(-px)$.

Comment: A typo sorry, I meant Is it valid to just say that $\lim _{n\to \infty}\exp(-px+O(1/n))=\lim _{n\to \infty}\exp(-px+o(1))=\exp(-px)$? by continuity of $\exp$, which you already confirmed

Comment: Yes, the use of o(1) there is correct now